# Problem With Sorting in Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

If I run a query like:

```
select * 
from personaldata 
order by 3
```

the we get the sorting according to ascending order of the 3rd column, but if I want to sorting according to descending order, then what should the query be?  I don't know the name of the 3rd column so i can not write like

```
select * 
from personaldata 
order by IDPERSONAL desc
```

I am using MS SQL Server 2000 as my database

Comment: 30 questions asked, and not 1 accepted answer?

Comment: Why would you not know the name of the third column? Not knowing column names is almost always a sign that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: 30 question, no accepts and no votes.  I'm sure he's contributing quite a lot based on the quality of those 30 questions.

Comment: Why don't you know your data model? At all? Both * and order by ordinal are bad habits. So much so that I highlight those two specifically in my "bad habits to kick" presentation that I give at user group meetings, SQL Saturdays, etc.

Comment: if you select * from tablename, you should see the column names in the result set. So no excuse for not knowing them.

Answer (score 7):

You can add `desc` after the ordinal

```
select * 
from personaldata 
order by 3 desc
```

Why wouldn't you know the name of the column though?

Both use of `*` and column ordinals in the `ORDER BY` clause are practices to be generally avoided IMO.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from personaldata order by 3 desc
```